# TypeError: Array to Tensor conversion

Tags: python, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

```
import torch
import numpy as np

X=torch.from_numpy(X).type(torch.float)
y=torch.from_numpy(y).type(torch.float)
X[:5],y[:,5]
```

I tried to convert X and y from array to tensor but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got Tensor)
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you X and y not numpy array, you can use

```
X=torch.from_numpy(np.array(X)).type(torch.float)
```

Comment: Yep I edited my code it gives the output thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the numpy array can be converted into a Tensor using just `from_numpy()`, it is not required to use `.type()` again.

Example:

```
X = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
X = torch.from_numpy(X)
print(X) # tensor([ 1,  2,  3])
```

Please check this Torch documentation page for detailed reference.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.from_numpy.html

Comment: Still it gave error ,so I used np.array ()